# Java External JAR Doesn't Seem To Be Working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Using Eclipse, Mslink.jar (creates shortcuts), Java 1.8.0

The coding that fails. The JOptionPane never appears when I export this out to a .JAR

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create an empty combo box with items of type String
    JComboBox<String> systems = new JComboBox<String>();

    // add items to the combo box
    systems.addItem("System1");
    systems.addItem("System2");
    systems.addItem("System5");
    systems.addItem("System6");
    systems.addItem("System7");
    systems.addItem("System9");
    systems.addItem("System10");
    systems.addItem("System12");
    systems.addItem("System14");
    systems.addItem("System15");
    systems.addItem("System16");
    systems.addItem("System17");
    systems.addItem("System18");
    systems.addItem("System19");
    systems.addItem("System20");
    systems.addItem("System21");
    systems.addItem("System22");
    systems.addItem("System24");
    systems.addItem("System30");
    systems.addItem("System34");
    systems.addItem("All Systems Install");

    systems.setEditable(true);

    JPanel steps = new JPanel();
    JPanel firstStep = new JPanel();
    JPanel secondStep = new JPanel();

    frame.setSize(1200, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    frame.add(steps);
    frame.add(firstStep);
    frame.add(secondStep);

    Button go = new Button("Go");
    Button go2 = new Button("Go");

    Label stepInstruction = new Label(
            "Please do each step in order to complete the process. First step requires you install Universal desktop for your system."
                    + " Second step requires your username to find Universal desktop install");
    Label instruction = new Label("Step 1: Please select a system to download from");
    Label instruction2 = new Label("Step 2: Press Go when Universal Desktop is Installed");

    // Steps Explained
    steps.add(stepInstruction);

    // First Step
    firstStep.add(instruction);
    firstStep.add(systems);
    firstStep.add(go);

    // Second Step
    secondStep.add(instruction2);
    secondStep.add(go2);

    go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String selectedSystem = (String) systems.getSelectedItem();

            System.out.println(selectedSystem);

            try {
                if (!selectedSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("All Systems Install")) {
                    // Open UD install page in Internet explorer
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe " + "https://"
                            + selectedSystem
                            + ".pos.infogenesisasp.com/infogenesis/install/universaldesktop/UniversalDesktop.application");

                    // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe
                    // "
                    // + "https://" + selectedSystem +
                    // ".pos.infogenesisasp.com/infogenesis/install/universaldesktop/");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e);
            }
            frame.validate();

        }
    });

    go2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String selectedSystem = (String) systems.getSelectedItem();
            String Username = System.getProperty("user.name");

            if (selectedSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("All Systems Install")) {
                String[] systems = { "System1", "System2", "System5", "System6", "System7", "System9", "System10",
                        "System12", "System14", "System15", "System16", "System17", "System18", "System19",
                        "System20", "System21", "System22", "System24", "System30", "System34" };
                for (int count = 0; count < systems.length; count++) {
                    try {
                        // Need to figure out a way to ensure the person installs UD before we can
                        // proceed
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe " + "https://"
                                + systems[count]
                                + ".pos.infogenesisasp.com/infogenesis/install/universaldesktop/UniversalDesktop.application");
                        count = systems.length;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Single System installer
                Installer(Username, selectedSystem);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Installion Completed!");
            }

        }

    });

}


import mslinks.ShellLink;

public static void createShortcut(String folder, String system) throws IOException
{
    ShellLink.createLink(folder, system);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Created Shortcut!");
}
```

File system:

[image]

This code works fine in Eclipse, but exporting to a JAR causes it to fail. Is there something missing preventing the Referenced Libaries Mslinks.jar from loading? I've tried everything in Eclipse's export

Comment: How do you export? You should probably specify classpath when you run your jar, or export the app as an uber jar with all dependencies inside.

Comment: What failure message are you getting?

Comment: @nitind that's the thing. Nothing errors. It just doesn't make it past the ShellLink call

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Export via Eclipse using either Runnable JAR or JAR. The mslinks.jar is in the "Libraries" + Selected in "Order and Export" of the Java Build Path

Comment: @Novabomb, first export it as Runnable Jar extracting required libraries into generated JAR. Do not forget to provide the right launch configuration with `main` method (you have one, right?). If that does not work for you, provide details what exactly happens when you run the jar and what's inside `MANIFEST.MF` file of the jar.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Yes I export it via Runnable Jar from my Main method (containing the code in the above question). Manifest.mf has 

"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main"

Comment: @Novabomb, it's inside the exported jar. `META-INF` -> `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I put the Runnable JAR into Eclipse and noticed no mslinks.jar in it. Manifest doesn't reference it either

Comment: @Novabomb, just open it with any zip archiver and see what's inside

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Using zip archiver, Manifest.mf has "Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: ."

Comment: @Novabomb, edit your question and provide the whole code of `Main` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228771/discussion-between-novabomb-and-pavel-smirnov).